# To remove check box from angular-ivh-treeview

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, treeview

I have created one tree using **angular-ivh-treeview** with objects, by following the code given at : https://github.com/iVantage/angular-ivh-treeview

The running sample of the tree is : http://jsbin.com/rigepe/1

The tree preparing fine with my data, but my requirement is to allow user to select one object at one time, so need to remove check boxes from the given code.

I have tried by making duplicate js with removing span of check box but its not working, also we have used both js with and without check boxes, but is also not working

What will be best way to remove check boxes from the tree.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove them in your HTML inside a `<div>` like this:

```
<ng-controller="MyCtrl as fancy">
  <div ivh-treeview="fancy.bag"
    ivh-treeview-use-checkboxes="false">
</div>
```